# AppendChild TypeError even though Child is HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, appendchild

I'm using Shopify and am trying to sort blog posts by a different date  than the publish date. Shopify Community Forums says the only real way to do it is using liquid to plug in the information and alter it via client side Javascript. I'm doing that by taking the div and the new date and placing it into an object in an array. The object is structured to have a div value and a date value like so:

```
0: 
date: "1563681600" 
div: " <div class="article-image">
          <a href="/blogs/upcoming/dog-days-of-summer">
            <div class="rimage-outer-wrapper" style="max-width: 750px"><div class="rimage-wrapper lazyload--placeholder" style="padding-top:60.0%"><img class="rimage__image lazyload fade-in " data-src="//cdn2.shopify.com/s/files/1/0152/7041/2388/articles/84th_2019-0721_slider_{width}x.jpg?v=1561562008" data-widths="[180, 220, 300, 360, 460, 540, 720, 900, 1080, 1296, 1512, 1728, 2048]" data-aspectratio="1.6666666666666667" data-sizes="auto" alt="DOG DAYS OF SUMMER"><noscript><img src="//cdn2.shopify.com/s/files/1/0152/7041/2388/articles/84th_2019-0721_slider_1024x1024.jpg?v=1561562008" alt="DOG DAYS OF SUMMER" class="rimage__image"></noscript></div></div>

          </a>
        </div>


        <div class="meta">

                  <span class="meta-item date">1563681600</span>
                  <span class="meta-item" id="time">1-3pm</span>
                  <span class="meta-item location">84th Street Location</span>


        </div>

        <h2><a href="/blogs/upcoming/dog-days-of-summer" title="">DOG DAYS OF SUMMER</a></h2>
        <div class="rte article-excerpt"><b>Books of Wonder</b><span>&nbsp;</span><span>is excited to host a picture book event: DOG DAYS OF SUMMER. Please join us on Sunday, July 21st at our 84th Street Store to celebrate four amazing picture books about dogs!</span></div>

        <p class="fullarticle"><a class="cta-link" href="/blogs/upcoming/dog-days-of-summer">Read more</a></p>
      "
```

The trouble I'm having now after sorting the array by date is how to take all these div elements and display them in the DOM. AppendChild throws an error even though these DIVS are captured using innerHTML. Here is the code:

```
function storeid() {
  var divName = document.getElementsByClassName('pullup');
  var className = document.getElementsByClassName('date');
  var classnameCount = className.length;
  var IdStore = new Array();

  for (var j = 0; j < classnameCount; j++) {
    var obj = {};
    var div = divName[j].innerHTML;
    var dateString = className[j].innerText;
    obj["div"] = div;
    obj["date"] = dateString;
    IdStore.push(obj);
  }
  console.log(IdStore);
  IdStore = IdStore.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.date - a.date
  });

  IdStore.forEach(el => {
    document.body.appendChild(el.div);
  })
}
storeid();
```

However despite specifying it only take the div I'm still getting the following error. `TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'`

Is appendChild not able to append this much? Or is there a better way of solving this?

Comment: `el.div` is a string, it's not a DIV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
var div = divName[j].innerHTML;
```

You're no longer dealing with a `Node`, it's a `string`. Remove the `.innerHTML` from the line and it should work.